# OPENJSON giving null value

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Express Edition 2016

Here is my query. It is returning null value.

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'F:\JKPM\18Aug2018\Mod1.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON) 
WITH(transactionId nvarchar(50))
```

My JSON is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "deviceTransactions": [{
            "transactionId": "3f147089-ff52-5552-a29b-cd32a7e2ba97",
            "organizationId": "9023179c-7888-4c5e-a831-28259b8a8872",
            "device": "JTLSPERF1",
            "event": "PUSH",
            "siteName": "TEST-SITE",
            "siteId": "5555f068-3ed2-4f83-b084-666f4f92734",
            "createdTime": "Sat, 18 Aug 2018 13:51:57 GMT",
            "updatedTime": "Sat, 18 Aug 2018 13:53:07 GMT",
            "userName": "test1",
            "userId": "test1",
            "status": "Failed",
            "details": {
                "count": 251,
                "deviceId": "44343570-7eb5-11e8-8160-057818f1057b",
                "error": {
                    "errorMessage": "Failed to start polling status of the Queue",
                    "stage": "MANAGE_PUSH",
                    "errorCode": "ERR021001"
                },
                "jcigId": "4rtr5aa6a2-71b5-455f-8890-7e2aa398b757"
            },
            "cancelledBy": ""
        }],
        "libraryTransactions": []
    },
    "success": true,
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

Comment: `transactionId` is not a top-level attribute. You want `$.data.deviceTransactions.transactionId` (or, more probably, you want a more sophisticated shredding of the JSON data if there may be more than one transaction). See the docs on [JSON path expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server).

Comment: Thanks. It is working

Answer (score 0):

transactionId is part of deviceTransactions which is also an array.  Here's an example of how you can use openjson in this situation:

```
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @json = N'
    {
        "data": {
            "deviceTransactions": [{
                "transactionId": "3f147089-ff52-5552-a29b-cd32a7e2ba97",
                "organizationId": "9023179c-7888-4c5e-a831-28259b8a8872",
                "device": "JTLSPERF1",
                "event": "PUSH",
                "siteName": "TEST-SITE",
                "siteId": "5555f068-3ed2-4f83-b084-666f4f92734",
                "createdTime": "Sat, 18 Aug 2018 13:51:57 GMT",
                "updatedTime": "Sat, 18 Aug 2018 13:53:07 GMT",
                "userName": "test1",
                "userId": "test1",
                "status": "Failed",
                "details": {
                    "count": 251,
                    "deviceId": "44343570-7eb5-11e8-8160-057818f1057b",
                    "error": {
                        "errorMessage": "Failed to start polling status of the Queue",
                        "stage": "MANAGE_PUSH",
                        "errorCode": "ERR021001"
                    },
                    "jcigId": "4rtr5aa6a2-71b5-455f-8890-7e2aa398b757"
                },
                "cancelledBy": ""
            }],
            "libraryTransactions": []
        },
        "success": true,
        "statusCode": 200
    }
    ';

    --This will get you just the transactionId
    SELECT *
    FROM   OPENJSON(@json, '$.data.deviceTransactions')
               WITH (
                        [transactionId] NVARCHAR(200) '$.transactionId')

    --This gets you all the columns                 
    SELECT *
    FROM   OPENJSON(@json, '$.data.deviceTransactions')
               WITH (
                        [transactionId] NVARCHAR(200) '$.transactionId'
                      , [organizationId] NVARCHAR(200) '$.organizationId'
                      , [device] NVARCHAR(200) '$.device'
                      , [event] NVARCHAR(200) '$.event'
                      , [siteName] NVARCHAR(200) '$.siteName'
                      , [createdTime] NVARCHAR(200) '$.createdTime'
                      , [updatedTime] NVARCHAR(200) '$.updatedTime'
                      , [userName] NVARCHAR(200) '$.userName'
                      , [userId] NVARCHAR(200) '$.userId'
                      , [status] NVARCHAR(200) '$.status'
                      , [count] NVARCHAR(200) '$.details.count'
                      , [deviceId] NVARCHAR(200) '$.details.deviceId'
                      , [errorMessage] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.details.error.errorMessage'
                      , [errorStage] NVARCHAR(200) '$.details.error.stage'
                      , [errorCode] NVARCHAR(200) '$.details.error.errorCode'
                      , [jcigId] NVARCHAR(200) '$.details.jcigId'
                      , [cancelledBy] NVARCHAR(200) '$.cancelledBy'
                    )
```

Comment: How would you output a single column, for `details` that contains the JSON fragment, viz: `{
                "count": 251,
                "deviceId": "44343570-7eb5-11e8-8160-057818f1057b",
                "error": {
                    "errorMessage": "Failed to start polling status of the Queue",
                    "stage": "MANAGE_PUSH",
                    "errorCode": "ERR021001"
                }`?